# How do I order the contents of a txt file

Tags: python-2.7

Hi this is the code I have at the moment which orders the following string by the age of the students 10,12,15 but how do I order it alphabetically starting with d ECT

```
>>> student_tuples = [
('john', 'A', 15),
('jane', 'B', 12),
('dave', 'B', 10),
]
>>> sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda student: student[2])

[('dave', 'B', 10), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('john', 'A', 15)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sort without any `key`:

```
sorted(student_tuples)
```

If the names can be lower case and capitalized use:

```
sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda student: student[0].lower())
```

Comment: @HarryAlexander Is this what you are looking for?